# move failed data to error table

Tags: ssis

how do we move the failed or error data to another table while importing data, in SSIS 2008 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the data flow destination object (OLE DB Destination, Excel Destination, Flat File Destination, etc.) , select the "Error Output" on the left hand side and change "fail component" under the "Error Column" to "Redirect Row" (dropdown) => select 'OK' . Then from that same data flow destination object, select the red arrow and direct the data flow either to a derived column or a new data flow destination (which would be the new error table). For testing purposes, you may want to add a data viewer to the red data flow.